# SCORM - Report failure

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

I'm trying to create a very simple SCORM course, but if I exit before the last page it still say that I have completed the course. Why is that?

- **[Source files for the simple course I'm building](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/775928/course-example.zip)**
- **[The
  SCORM ENGINE Debug Log](http://cloud.scorm.com/sc/guest/ViewDebugLog?logId=1018569b-84d0-4872-8f00-129449a5ee02&courseTitle=Test)**

I'm grateful for any help I get.

Comment: Are you creating it from scratch or using some tool?

Comment: From scratch with Dreamweaver. Is there a tool you could recommend? I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Not really, just asking. 
Where are you testing it? I tested it on a LMS and it didn't send any completion status before I reached the "completed" page

Comment: I'm testing it on http://cloud.scorm.com. So it works for you?

Comment: I think it's something wrong with my imsmanifest.xml, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes it works for me. The imsmanifest file looks ok as well. Are you sure that it's not some scorm cloud's settings that's making it appear as completed?

Comment: I can't find anything, what LMS did you test the course in?

Comment: I tested some more and found this in the debug log: Missing mastery score or raw score, setting to completed. Maybe this is something?

Comment: Yes, it may be. Try setting a mastery_score and see if it makes any difference, there should be an option in Dreamweaver. Alternatively, you can specify this directly to your imsmanifest.xml file, inside the <item>, like this:
<adlcp:masteryscore>80</adlcp:masteryscore>

I used the eFront LMS to test it.

Comment: Still doesn't work properly even I write a a master score inside <item>. In some LMS is stand completed every time even if you exit on the first page and inte some LMS is never change status to completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I needed to use set a `cmi.core.lesson_status`.

Now it works just fine!